# одинаковый размер нескольким элементам flutter

Tags: flutter

```
ListView(children: [
      Row(children: [
        Container(child: Text("TextTextText"),),
      ]),
      Row(children: [
        Container(child: Text("TextText"),),
      ]),
      Row(children: [
        Container(child: Text("Text"),),
      ]),
    ])
```

Как сделать чтобы у всех контейнеров была ширина самого большого из них?

Comment: Распишите подробности задачи, может нужно по-другому организовать layout?

Comment: @VAndrJ Делаю свой DataTable с прокруткой. И должны быть Scrollbar по бокам

Answer (score 0):

Используйте стандартный виджет [DataTable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html).

Для прокрутки заверните в ScrollView. И по примеру из документации результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
// ну или используйте какой package, к примеру, bidirectional_scroll_view
return SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    child: DataTable(
      columns: const <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(
          label: Text(
            'Name',
            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          ),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text(
            'Age',
            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          ),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text(
            'Role',
            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          ),
        ),
      ],
      rows: const <DataRow>[
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
            DataCell(Text('19')),
            DataCell(Text('Student')),
          ],
        ),
        // Здесь много копипасты
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('William')),
            DataCell(Text('27')),
            DataCell(Text(
                'Associate ProfessorAssociate ProfessorAssociate Professor')),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Как добавить сюда фильтрация, сортировку и групировку?

Comment: @Jedy , подстановкой нужных данных, как в последнем примере документации и демонстрации на видео "DataTable (Flutter Widget of the Week)"

Comment: И прокрутка тут не та, header должно быть видно всегда

Comment: И Scrollbar`oв нету.

Comment: Разве группировку сделаешь подстановкой?

Comment: Я пробовал использовать стандартный но понял что он мало развит и пошёл по пути собственного DataTable.

Comment: @Jedy, скроллбары добавляются простым заворачиванием ScrollView в `Scrollbar(child:`. Ну и остальные случаи так же по отдельности можно порешать, т.к. в Flutter всё есть виджет. Но и новое самописное тоже классный вариант.

Comment: Так вот я и задал вопрос по самописному, потому что не знаю как сделать чтобы ячейки одного столбца были одного размера.

Comment: @Jedy, гляньте может подойдёт https://pub.dev/packages/table_sticky_headers или https://pub.dev/packages/horizontal_data_table. Ну либо подружить свой sticky header с DataTable. В общем, собрать из крупных готовых кусков нужное, а не писать с мельчайших.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую